Scrapy returning 400 when request returns 200
I'm trying to scrape a website using Scrapy and I'm stuck because no matter what I do I cannot get a valid response. I need a proxy to access this website, and when I use Python's requests library, it works fine and I get 200:
url = "http://search.example.com/api"
body = '{"data":"stuff"}'
proxies = {"http": "http://user:pass@domain:24032"}
headers = {
    "authorization": "Basic abc123",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "user-agent": (
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/"
        "537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg"
        "/12"
    ),
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,ro;q=0.7",
    "origin": "https://www.example.com",
    "referer": "https://www.example.com/",
    "sec-ch-ua": (
        '"Microsoft Edge";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";' 'v="123"'
    ),
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-model": '""',
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"macOS"',
    "sec-ch-ua-platform-version": '"14.5.0"',
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
}
response = requests.post(
    url=url, data=body, headers=headers, proxies=proxies
)
# response.status_code == 200

When I use Scrapy, however, I get 400:
import scrapy


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    url = "https://search.example.com/api"

    def start_requests(self):
        body = '{"data":"stuff"}'
        headers = {
            "authorization": "Basic abc123",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "user-agent": (
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/"
                "537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg"
                "/12"
            ),
            "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,ro;q=0.7",
            "origin": "https://www.example.com",
            "referer": "https://www.example.com/",
            "sec-ch-ua": (
                '"Microsoft Edge";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";'
                'v="123"'
            ),
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "sec-ch-ua-model": '""',
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"macOS"',
            "sec-ch-ua-platform-version": '"14.5.0"',
            "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
            "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
        }
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=self.url,
            method="POST",
            body=body,
            headers={
                "content-length": str(len(body)),
                **headers,
            },
            callback=self.parse,
            dont_filter=True,
        )

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        # response.status == 400
        # response.text == ""

I'm using a custom middleware to handle proxies:
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy import HttpProxyMiddleware


class CustomProxyDownloaderMiddleware(HttpProxyMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta["proxy"] = "http://user:pass@domain:24032"
        super().process_request(request, spider)

Initially, when I inspected response.requests.headers after making the request in each scenario, I had slightly different values. However, I've managed to make changes so that now the values are identical. Still, the response is different. When I try the exact same request on Postman, I have yet another outcome:

If I just configure basic auth and use Postman's default headers, the request waits forever and I never get a response.
If I manually copy/paste all headers, I get a 400 with the following body:

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Invalid URL</H1>
The requested URL "&#91;no&#32;URL&#93;", is invalid.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;9&#46;3662645f&#46;1725629283&#46;22cfdad7
<P>https&#58;&#47;&#47;errors&#46;edgesuite&#46;net&#47;9&#46;3662645f&#46;1725629283&#46;22cfdad7</P>
</BODY></HTML>

What is going on? How can I be getting such different outcomes with such similar requests?

The most common reason for getting 400 when having a big list of explicit headers is an explicit content-length and, yes, you have one, even though it's hidden in the code unlike the usual pattern.
